# I am unable to get FLEX Debugger to work after installation

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, autolayout, uikit

Please I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I have installed Flex via cocopods but it's still not showing up when I run my app in the simulator.

[image: My Simulator]

[image: Cocopods installation]

Comment: You said you installed via pods, but you didn't mention if you followed the rest of the usage instructions. Do you, for example, call `[[FLEXManager sharedManager] showExplorer];`? Also, the project was last updated 6 years ago, so I'm not sure how much I'd rely on it.

Comment: No, I haven't done that. I have no idea where to put that part of the code. Can please point me in the right direction?

Comment: See the documentation at: https://github.com/greedbell/FLEX